# rational eigenvalues of integer matrix are integral

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A=A^T$ a real symmetric matrix with integer entries. How do you prove that a rational eigenvalue of A is integral?

Comment: Do you mean "integral" as in "integral over $\Bbb Z$" or "integral" as is an element of $\Bbb Z$?  The former case isn't too bad; the latter, I just don't know!

Comment: Any attempt at solution, also is there any motivation for this question?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Note that the eigenvalues of $A$ are the zeros of the characteristic polynomial, which is a *monic* polynomial (that is, the coefficient of the highest degree is $1$) with integer coefficients.

From there, apply the [rational root theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem) (or, more specifically, the integer root theorem).

The fact that $A$ is symmetric apparently has nothing to do with the result.

Comment: Well, symmetric matrix implies that the eigenvalues are real, and I think also that the left and right eigenvectors of $A$ are the same.

Comment: Both of those things have true, and have no impact on my proof of the statement.